Alternatives to COUNTA
I have an excel formula that goes like this:
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(Sheet2!C:C,(Sheet2'!Y:Y="Yes")*(Sheet2!J:J>=Sheet1!C2)))

The C column in the second sheet is the clients names. The Y column is the question if it's a new client. The J column is the date of the receipt and C2 in the first sheet is the today date.
However, it always show me the answer 1, even if it's truly 0 because there's no clients with receipt in the future yet. Is there a formula that can do the same thing, which is to give me the number of new clients (only counted once) that have receipt in the future ?

Use SUM() --> =SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER(Sheet2!C:C,(Sheet2'!Y:Y="Yes")*(Sheet2!J:J>=Sheet1!C2))<>"")) also it is not right to use the whole ranges, instead convert source data into Structured References and use the references in the formulas.

Unfortunately, it still tell me that there's an error in the formula.

Unfortunately, we dont see any sample data, so it is quite hard to assume what you really have on your end. So it will be helpful if you post some sample data like others do. BTW, basis on your post context I have posted a sample which works on my end!

Do check if you have any error in your data, that will also an error : =SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER(Sheet2!C:C,IFERROR((Sheet2'!Y:Y="Yes")*(Sheet2!J:J>=Sheet1!C2),0)))<>""))

COUNTA() will always return 1 even if there is nothing as it returns an error #CALC!

Here is one way of doing this using SUM() function, you can also use ROWS() function, but it would return an error if there is none.


=SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B11,(C2:C11="Yes")*(D2:D11>=F2),""))<>""))


Alternatively, one can use ROWS() as mentioned:
=ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B11,(C2:C11="Yes")*(D2:D11>=F2),"")))


Sample data posted based on the context of the OP.

One more great alternative as suggested by Tom Sharpe Sir
=SUM(--(COUNTIFS(A:A,UNIQUE(A:A),B:B,"Yes",C:C,">="&E2)>0)) 



Just for the record, your formulas do work fine on full-column references as well like =SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,(B:B="Yes")*(C:C>=E2),""))<>"")) . Another one might be =SUM(--(COUNTIFS(A:A,UNIQUE(A:A),B:B,"Yes",C:C,">="&E2)>0))

@TomSharpe Sir, absolutely stunning ! You always come up with new ideas. But the problem here is different OP is not posting any examples. So it really depends. Thanks again btw!

I think you're formula wasn't working yesterday because I miswrite something, because now it does work. Thank you. Sorry for all the derangement.

Hi @ClaraMonspiette you don't have to be sorry about anything nor you need to apologize, our goal in this forum is always try to ask users to post some data using markdown table. it not only you but helps us to construct some answers, so that each of us can learn.

Using INDEX to automatically include new entries (and ignore blanks):
=ROWS(UNIQUE(
FILTER($C$1:INDEX($C1:$C$200,$A$7),
($Y$1:INDEX($Y1:$Y$200,$A$7)="Yes")*($J$1:INDEX($J$1:$J$200,$A$7)>=$A$4)
)))

Rows with answers is calculated (in A7) with:
=COUNTA($C$1:$C$200)



=SUM(($Y$1:INDEX($Y1:$Y$200,$A$7)="Yes")*($J$1:INDEX($J$1:$J$200,$A$7)>=$A$4)) works thank you

Glad to hear it! Please do take a look at using names - it is very helpful.

@ClaraMonspiette again if the given formula works for you --> =SUM(($Y$1:INDEX($Y1:$Y$200,$A$7)="Yes")*($J$1:INDEX($J$1:$J$200,$A$7)>=$A$4)) which is not accounting for uniques. I am really not sure on the question and the answer posted which is being accepted completely different.

Well, in the exemple, there was cell A7 that counted separately counta, so I put unique after the counta as such : =COUNTA(UNIQUE($C$1:$C$200))

In the example answer posted by user it has nothing with UNIQUE() but it doesn't reflect anything on your OP as well. Completely missing something here. and using =COUNTA(UNIQUE($C$1:$C$200))  this will give you FALSE POSITIVES because you have conditions. more over the user has also not posted any caveat on using volatile functions, generally in this forum we never suggest on using volatile functions.

You're right, I tough it works, but after some tests it doesn't.

@ClaraMonspiette that is the reason why I have asked you to create some sample data like 5/10 lines and post it, you will get proper response which will help each other to learn something!

Hey @Clar, I'm sorry that I had overlooked the unique requirement. Anyway, I have updated the answer now (also, removed suggestion with OFFSET adhering to the admonition from long time users.)
